# passing particular domain from column

Tags: r

I am trying to pass particular domain else all the values replace with NULL
if BB= TRUE, or If BB = False then all the values should be there.

```
df6 <- data.frame(name=c("try,xab","xab,Lan","mhy,mun","vgtu,mmc","dgsy,aaf","kull,nnhu","hula,njam","mund,jiha","htfy,ntha","bhr,gydbt","sgyu,hytb","vdti,kula","mftyu,huta","ibdy,vcge","cday,bhsue","ajtu,nudj"),
                  email=c("xab.try@ybcd.com","Lan.xab@ybcd.com","tth.vgu@ybcd.com","mmc.vgtu@ybcd.com","aaf.dgsy@partnt.com","nnhu.kull@ybcd.com","njam.hula@ybcd.com","jiha.mund@ybcd.com","ntha.htfy@ybcd.com","gydbt.bhr@ybcd.com","hytb.sgyu@ybcd.com","kula.vdti@ybcd.com","huta.mftyu@ybcd.com","ggat.khul@ybcd.com","bhsue.cday@ybcd.com","nudj.ajtu@ybcd.com"))

BB=TRUE
col_drop <- c("partnt.com")
df6 <- ifelse(BB==TRUE,
              df6 <- df6[ , !(names(df6) %in% col_drop)],df6) %>% as.data.frame()
```

the output should be like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :)

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df6 <- data.frame(name=c("try,xab","xab,Lan","mhy,mun","vgtu,mmc","dgsy,aaf","kull,nnhu","hula,njam","mund,jiha","htfy,ntha","bhr,gydbt","sgyu,hytb","vdti,kula","mftyu,huta","ibdy,vcge","cday,bhsue","ajtu,nudj"),
                  email=c("xab.try@ybcd.com","Lan.xab@ybcd.com","tth.vgu@ybcd.com","mmc.vgtu@ybcd.com","aaf.dgsy@partnt.com","nnhu.kull@ybcd.com","njam.hula@ybcd.com","jiha.mund@ybcd.com","ntha.htfy@ybcd.com","gydbt.bhr@ybcd.com","hytb.sgyu@ybcd.com","kula.vdti@ybcd.com","huta.mftyu@ybcd.com","ggat.khul@ybcd.com","bhsue.cday@ybcd.com","nudj.ajtu@ybcd.com"))
col_drop <- c("partnt.com")

mutate(df6, email = if_else(grepl(col_drop, email), email, NULL))
#>          name               email
#> 1     try,xab                <NA>
#> 2     xab,Lan                <NA>
#> 3     mhy,mun                <NA>
#> 4    vgtu,mmc                <NA>
#> 5    dgsy,aaf aaf.dgsy@partnt.com
#> 6   kull,nnhu                <NA>
#> 7   hula,njam                <NA>
#> 8   mund,jiha                <NA>
#> 9   htfy,ntha                <NA>
#> 10  bhr,gydbt                <NA>
#> 11  sgyu,hytb                <NA>
#> 12  vdti,kula                <NA>
#> 13 mftyu,huta                <NA>
#> 14  ibdy,vcge                <NA>
#> 15 cday,bhsue                <NA>
#> 16  ajtu,nudj                <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: BB=TRUE is also one more condition

Comment: sorry, you can try `mutate(df6, email = if_else(BB & grepl(col_drop, email), email, NULL))` :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> df6[!grepl('partnt.com', df6$email), 'email'] <- NA
> df6
         name               email
1     try,xab                <NA>
2     xab,Lan                <NA>
3     mhy,mun                <NA>
4    vgtu,mmc                <NA>
5    dgsy,aaf aaf.dgsy@partnt.com
6   kull,nnhu                <NA>
7   hula,njam                <NA>
8   mund,jiha                <NA>
9   htfy,ntha                <NA>
10  bhr,gydbt                <NA>
11  sgyu,hytb                <NA>
12  vdti,kula                <NA>
13 mftyu,huta                <NA>
14  ibdy,vcge                <NA>
15 cday,bhsue                <NA>
16  ajtu,nudj                <NA>
>
```

Comment: BB=TRUE  should also be there

Comment: Can you explain what's that condition? What BB refers to.

Answer (score 0):

below should work:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df6)
BB <- TRUE
domain_to_keep <- "partnt.com"
df6[BB & !grepl(paste0("@", domain_to_keep, "$"), email) , email := "" ]
```

Comment: Error: `:=` can only be used within a quasiquoted argument

Comment: you are running all previous lines without error? are your packages really old or something? code runs fine here...